# How to let Ctrl + Page Down switch tabs inside Vim in Terminal.app?

Tags: macos, mac, vim, terminal, shortcuts

When running vim inside the Terminal in Ubuntu, I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> or <kbd>Page Down</kbd> to switch between the vim tabs. How do I set up this for Terminal.app or iTerm2 for Mac OS X? I have a Macbook Air (2011) so I don't have 'proper' <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd> keys, if that matters.

I have tried to set up various escape codes, but so far nothing works.

EDIT: I don't have privs to answer my own question, but here is the answer:

### ANSWER:

I found the correct escape sequences.
In Terminal.app's keyboard settings,

set "control page up" to "send string to shell:", with this value: "\033[5;5~"

set "control page down" to "send string to shell:", with this value: "\033[6;5~"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't have actual `pageup` and `pagedown` keys on your keyboard there is no way to map these to anything.

- `<C-PageDown>` is an alternative to `:tabnext`, `:tabn` and `gt`.
- `<C-PageUp>` is an alternative to `:tabprevious`, `:tabN` and `gT`.

I strongly suggest you use `gt` and `gT` instead, they follow Vim's grammar (lowercase letter for "forward commands", uppercase for "backward commands") and so are very easy to memorize.

If you don't like `gt/gT` you can map them to something more to your taste:

```
nnoremap <C-Up> gT
nnoremap <C-Down> gt
```

But I don't think it's necessary.

Your example (a `PageUp/PageDown`-less keyboard) seems to be a rather nice example of the intelligence of Vim's seemingly weird design decisions.

**--EDIT (as per the asker's request)--**

> I found the correct escape sequences. In Terminal.app's keyboard
>   settings,
>
> set "control page up" to "send string to shell:", with this value:
>   "\033[5;5~"
>
> set "control page down" to "send string to shell:", with this value:
>   "\033[6;5~"

Comment: Hi, I cant answer my own question it seems, but I found the escape sequences that made it work. Could you perhaps include them in your answer? Thanks (If you do I will accept it :)

Comment: The MBA simulates PageUp and PageDown with <function key> and ArrowUp / ArrowDown

Comment: OK, I've edited my answer. But I think you could POST an answer, don't you?

Comment: romainl: The privilege system didn't allow me to post an answer to my own question, I'm a new user here.

Thanks for your answer and help!

Comment: Since I had to search for it: the `\033` part of the string needs be generated by Esc+[ .

Answer (score 10):

Based on ramn's answer and just as a reference, this is how to solve this problem in `iTerm2`:

1. Go to `iTerm` / `Preferences...` / `Profiles` / `Keys`
2. Press the `+` button to add a profile shortcut
3. Use shortcut: `^Page Up`, action: "Send Escape sequence", value `[5;5~`
4. Use shortcut: `^Page Down`, action: "Send Escape sequence", value `[6;5~`